# CABasicAnimation of object around itself (360 degrees)

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, rotation, cabasicanimation

Here's my Animation code:

```
  CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
    fullRotation.duration = 4;
    fullRotation.repeatCount= 1000;
    [[stick layer] addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"60"];

      fullRotation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
```

I'm trying to rotate "stick" around itself , but it seems that it's rotating around another point , which is by default the origin. What can I do to make it accomplish a full 360 degrees rotation around itself? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the anchor point of stick use:

```
stick.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0,1.0);
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/anchorPoint

The rotation code I use:

```
CABasicAnimation *rotateAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rotateAnim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    rotateAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    rotateAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(360 * M_PI / 180.0f)];
    rotateAnim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    rotateAnim.duration = 2.5;
    rotateAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    [view.layer addAnimation:rotateAnim forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

Comment: "The default value of this property is (0.5, 0.5)" so basically if the object doesn't rotate around its center , it means that there are flaws in the design right?

Comment: Therefore , if I want the correct rotation around the center , I should design the object so that its real center is in the center of the canvas and in xcode I should put an imageview which has the exact same dimensions as the canvas of the object design. Right?

Comment: Yeah by default it should rotate around the centre, is that what you are after?

Comment: @Joseph right, thats what we have had to do in the past.